# Make the console fullscreen on any windows verison

Tags: c++, winapi, console

So i'm trying to make a console aplication fullscreen (actual fullscreen not just windowed). I didn't quite understand but according to [microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt427362.aspx) it seems like  computers with the 2016 version of the *server technical preview* can have the console fullscreen (hotkey: ALT+ENTER).

What am i asking is : Can you have a function which makes a console aplication true fullscreen before this 2016 *server techical preview* for all windows versions (ofc after windows XP)?

Note: I have some laptops at home with WIN 10 , WIN 8.1 and WIN 7 and i can test the if it truly works.

What i have tried:

1.

```
/*The ALT+ENTER method*/
/*It worked on my WIN10 laptop, failed on the other ones.*/
/*On the WIN7 it also said "Console does not support fullscreen mode".*/
void fullscreen()
{
    keybd_event(VK_MENU,0x38,0,0);
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x1c,0,0);
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x1c,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
    keybd_event(VK_MENU,0x38,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
}
```

2.

```
/*Same results as the one above.*/
/*On the WIN8.1 GetLastError() returns 87 (aka invalid parameter)*/
void fullscreen()
{
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE,NULL);
}
```

Also please let me know if there is a method of testing if the machine has the *2016 server technical preview*. Thanks.

Comment: The x86 specific full screen hardware mode never worked on Vista, 7 nor 8.

Comment: @Anders doesn't mean they couldn't emulate it.

Comment: @Anders are u saying that the only way to make it happen on 7,8 etc is so simply stretch it on the screen size ?

Comment: I'm saying that because of the new WDDM/DWM model in Vista the hardware mode was dropped. It might work if you use a old XP display driver, I don't remember.

Comment: @CainWildtale, in NT 6 and NT 10  the console cannot be made fullscreen via `SetConsoleDisplayMode`. In NT 10 it fails with `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`, even though fullscreen is supported again with a new implementation. Also, in recent versions of the NT 10 console, even `GetConsoleDisplayMode` fails with an `NTSTATUS` code (0xC0070006) due to some WinAPI failing in the console host process (conhost.exe) with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (0x0006). There's no simple way to determine if the console is already full screen, which is needed to know whether to send the toggle command. It's all broken.

Comment: Apparently Michael Niksa at Microsoft is [looking into](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1236) the `GetConsoleDisplayMode` failure. Hopefully that issue will  be resolved in the Spring Creators update, and maybe, just maybe, while fixing that code he'll get ambitious and implement `SetConsoleDisplayMode` again.

Answer (score 0):

as a batch programmer, i would say that if  you use windows you must learn a bit of prompt.
to avoid your problem, you can use the function system that uses actual batch strings of code added to your c++ code:

you should use

```
    system ("mode 1000");
```

Comment: I know quite a bit of  batch files and that command over there will stretch the console 1000 by 1000. I want something that can addapt to any screen. What if he has a higher resolution and a small font ? That wont even be windowed fullscreen.
And what if the user has a small screen res ? The whole console won't fit on the screen so easily.

Comment: I actually don't know how to implement it in c++, but there's still a batch code to use that can definitely solve your problem. Tomorrow i will show you the code, because now i'm really tired.